# C# Linq All Condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of codes as follows

```
public Code{
    int id;
    string Description;
}

List<Code> AllCodes;
```

I have a list of selected codes from a different source.

```
var relatedCodes = //gets the list of int 'id's from a different source.
```

Using `linq`, I need to join `AllCodes` and `relatedCodes` so that the resultant list contains all the `Code` elements of the given `id`s. It is known that all the `int` values in `relatedCodes` are valid `id`s in `AllCodes`. [`relatedCodes` is an `int` array]

```
result = //how to write the linq expression?
```

I was trying something like this but it throws error

```
result = AllCodes.All(x => x.Code==relatedCodes);
```

Comment: Something with Where and Contains. What have you tried?

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard, could you please provide code examples of what you've tried thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is nothing to do with `Join`. Question is briefly `How can I get the Codes of which relatedCodes contains the id?`. You can use `Where` to filter your list.

```
var result = AllCodes.Where( c=> relatedCodes.Contains(c.id));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Code> result = AllCodes.Where(x => relatedCodes.Contains(x.id)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:**
Since `relatedCodes` is of type `int[]` (I used an array of type `Code`) the solution looks slightly different, but not by too much:

```
var relatedCodes = new int[2] { 2, 4 };

var joinedCodes = from ac in AllCodes
                  join rc in relatedCodes on ac.Id equals rc
                  select ac;
```

**ORIGINAL answer**

One possibility is to use join:

```
void Main()
{
    var AllCodes = new List<Code>() 
    {
        new Code() {Id = 1, Description="Foo1"},
        new Code() {Id = 2, Description="Bar2"},
        new Code() {Id = 3, Description="Foo3"},
        new Code() {Id = 4, Description="Bar4"}
    };

    var relatedCodes = new Code[2] 
    {
        new Code() {Id = 2, Description="Bar2"},
        new Code() {Id = 4, Description="Bar4"}
    };

    var joinedCodes = from ac in AllCodes
                      join rc in relatedCodes on ac.Id equals rc.Id
                      select ac;
    joinedCodes.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Code{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Ouput:

[image]